# Multiselect and form binding on Edit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have an issue with editing model which has collection of linked other models.
I am using a a strong-typed view with model class:

```
   public class GroupViewModel
   {
       public GroupViewModel()
       {
           Group = new Group();
           Sections = new List<Section>();
       }

       public Group Group { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Section> Sections { get; set; }
   }
```

In the Edit method of controller I filling both fields with correct data and pass it to the view. View displaying my viewmodel correctly, multiselect appears and filled with data passed, the same about Group.

But after I sending it back on form submit I am getting an arror in ModelState, something like "*The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Myapp.Models.Section' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.*"

Whether ASP.NET handles children collections correctly or I need to handle it using old FormCollection?

UPD: Maybe application cannot convert parsed int to Section due to Section is class and some fields may not be acquired from client (actually, multiselect using only Id and Name, but other fields are omitted)?

**UPD1: As temporary solution I changed code** as:

```
   public class GroupViewModel
   {
       public GroupViewModel()
       {
           Group = new Group();
           Sections = new List<Section>();
       }

       public Group Group { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<int> SectionsIds { get; set; }      //here
       public IEnumerable<Section> SectionsDS { get; set; }   //as here
   }
```

In the view I am binding it like:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SectionIds,
    new MultiSelectList(Model.SectionsDS, "Id", "Name"));
```

And after retrieving view model synchronizing 2 collection - virtual navigation and IDs manually.

Answer (score 0):

Read this - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

in your view, something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(), i++)
{
   Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Foo1);
   Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Foo2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it is incompatible with listbox with nultiselection

Comment: meant only as an example to learn from - read more here - http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/tip-of-the-day-198-asp-net-mvc-listbox-controls/